# User input java array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a program that will query the user for the size of a 2-dimentional array, and then fill the array with sequential integer data, starting with a user defined initial vale. I have some part of the program but I am stuck at the end.

Comment: Stuck how?  What's wrong?

Comment: Try not to ask questions without giving context: What have you tried? What error are you getting? What don't you understand? [More info](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
int value = scanner.nextInt(); 
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        array[i][j] = value + i * columns + j;
    }
}
```

Try that out and it should work as expected.

Input:

```
2
2
5
```

Output:

```
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
```

Be sure to use `Arrays.deepToString(array)` to print out the array properly.

This will print out the row and column it is going to request for, then prompt you to fill it in.

Also:

```
array[rows][columns] = scanner.nextInt();
```

Will not work as you expect. That will fill in a single cell in the array, not to even mention it will throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: is there a way that will allow only one number to be inputed. For example in a 2x2 if the number typed in is 1, then the numbers wii read 1 and 2 in the first row and 3 and 4 in the second row

Comment: @user2967009 sorry I misread your question. I have already fixed the program to work as expected.

Comment: Im sorry I'm a little confused would u be able to type out the whole code so it runs perfectly?

Comment: Everything was fine up to the line I pointed out that would throw the exception. Just replace everything after and including that line.